# How to exclude nodes with matching field values using EntityFieldQuery

Tags: entities, database

This relates to a classified listings site, where nodes have an expiry date (date, field_period, start/end = value/value2) and a notifications field (text, checkboxes, 336=two weeks, 672=four weeks).

We want to query for nodes which are going to expire between two and four weeks from now -

```
$period = 672;
$paid_date_max = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime('+' . $period . ' hours'));
$paid_date_min = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime('+' . $period/2 . ' hours'));

$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'entry')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
  ->fieldCondition('field_period', 'value2', $paid_date_max, '<')
  ->fieldCondition('field_period', 'value2', $paid_date_min, '>=')
  ->fieldCondition('field_period', 'value2', 'NULL', '!=')
  ->addMetaData('account', user_load(1));
$result = $query->execute();
```

That works fine, but includes nodes which have already been sent a reminder (in which case field_expiry_notifications will contain a value matching $period). field_expiry_notifications may have multiple values, so we need to accept only nodes where NONE of the field_period_notifications values match $period.

Q: How to exclude from the above resultset any nodes with a matching expiry_notifications value?

Comment: On trying to express this in SQL I realised it might not be possible without subqueries, so maybe this isn't a supported use. Worth throwing a bounty at anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you do need a subquery here. [Apparently](http://drupal.org/node/1214150), you can actually do that with EntityFieldQuery. So first create your subquery, something like this:

```
$subquery = db_select('your_field_data_table', 't');
$subquery->addField('t', 'nid');
$subquery->condition('field_period_notifications', $period);
```

That gives you all nodes that *have* a matching value. Then add this to your EntityFieldQuery to exclude those:

```
->fieldCondition('field_period', 'nid', $subquery, 'NOT IN')
```

Or maybe you can do:

```
->entityCondition('entity_id', $subquery, 'NOT IN')
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you need is an OR query (but also an AND); Look into altering the query after making it. This is probably the better explanation of that I've seen: http://treehouseagency.com/blog/fredric-mitchell/2012/02/21/or-queries-entityfieldquery